# Deploy a war in Jboss 7.2.0 and JDK 1.8

Tags: java, deployment, java-8, jboss7.x, war

I'm trying to deploy a compiled and working WAR file on **JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final "Janus"**

1. When I use the **JDK 1.7** the deploy is **OK**. In the logs I see something like that:

   *19:44:50,191 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) Initializing Deployment Scanner Extension*
2. The same WAR, with same JBoss, on same OS, but on **JDK 1.8** does not deploy. I do not see in the logs the **org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner** is run.

I guess there is some problems with modules. But I can't find in official JBoss [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2.Beta/html-single/configuration_guide/#reference_of_switches_and_arguments_to_pass_at_server_runtime) any tips.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to recompile the code at a minimum.  If your code compiles under JDK 7 but not under 8, I'd expect to see compiler error messages.

Comment: The code compiles both on 1.7 and 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.x doesn't work on JDK8.

You have to upgrade AS to WildFly 8 or 9 or keep using JDK7.

More info [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/926279#926279)

And you can download wildfly
[here](http://wildfly.org/downloads/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's quite strange that in official documentation from RedHat for JBOSS 7.2 there are a lot of different precisions for JDK 8, but in fact there is any note that is not compatible.